# Context is undefined in Apollo RESTDataSource

Tags: node.js, apollo, nock, restdatasource

While upgrading from Apollo v2 to v3, I'm trying to make some external API calls to an auth server. Currently, I'm using nock to intercept the requests inside of a unit test.

The GET request keeps failing when I try to attach a token in the request header because the context is undefined. Why would the context be undefined here? This worked prior to upgrading.

server.js

```
const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server-koa'),
CustomApi = require('../service/customapi'),
...;

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: [DateTypeDefinition, root.typeDef, user.typeDef, ...],
    resolvers: [{Date: DateResolver}, root.resolvers, user.resolvers, ...],
    validationRules: [depthLimit(10)],
    plugins: [
        graphqlLogger
    ],
    dataSources: () => {
        return {
            customApi: new CustomApi()
        };
    },
    context: async (req) => {
        const user = await extract(req);
        return {
            user,
            ...
        }
    }
})

module.exports = apolloServer;
```

resolvers.js

```
syncAccount: async (parent, _, context) => {
        allowed(context.user);
        const reviewer = await getReviewerByEmail(context.user.email);
        if (reviewer && reviewer.status === 'INVITED') {
            const account = await context.dataSources.customApi.getAccount();
            ...
}
```

customapi.js

```
const {RESTDataSource} = require('@apollo/datasource-rest'),
config = require('config')

class CustomAPI extends RESTDataSource {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.baseURL = `${config.customapi.url}/path/api`;
        }

        willSendRequest(path, request) {
            //ERROR HERE
            console.log("willSendRequest - this.context: ", this.context); // prints undefined
            request.headers.set('Authorization', this.context.user.token);
        }

        async getAccount() {
            return await this.get('account');
        }
        ...
}
```

package.json versions:

```
"@apollo/datasource-rest": "^6.2.2",
"@koa/cors": "^3.1.0",
"apollo-server": "^3.13.0",
"apollo-server-koa": "^3.13.0",
"dataloader": "^2.0.0",
"graphql": "^16.8.1",
"graphql-depth-limit": "^1.1.0",
"graphql-scalars": "^1.22.4",
"graphql-upload": "^13.0.0",
"koa": "^2.13.0",
"koa-bodyparser": "^4.3.0",
"koa-jwt": "^4.0.0",
"koa-router": "^9.4.0",
...
```

Comment: When you later move from 3 to 4, keep in mind that the `context` argument moves out of the `ApolloServer` constructor: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of retrieving the context from within the RESTDataSource, I deleted the willSendRequest overridden function and instead passed in the token:

```
async getAccount(token) {
        return await this.get('account', undefined, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': token
            }
        });
    }
```

EDIT:

If you are using apollo/datasource-rest version 5 or 6 now, the function has changed to use only 2 function parameters now, combine your url params with your headers:

```
async getAccount(token) {
        return await this.get('account', {
            param1: param1,
            param2: param2,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': token
            }
        });
    }
```